# frame.addEventListener doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, focus, addeventlistener

I have a document that loads into an iframe. Now I would like to know whenever the "body" element of that document gets the event "focus". I've had success using addEventListener in other browsers, but IE (8 to be specific) gives me this error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I implemented it like this:

```
//This works in Chrome, Opera, Safari and Firefox but not in IE

var myFrame = document.getElementById("my-i-frame");
var frame = (myFrame.contentWindow || myFrame.contentDocument);
frame.addEventListener("focus", function(){alert('works')},false);
```

I also tried:

```
frame.document.addEventListener("focus", function(){alert('works')},false);
```

Before you ask WHY WOULD YOU DO THAT?, let me explain:

I've created an html WYSIWYG editor and I would like resize my iframe when the user clicks inside the frame to start editing. To do that, the only method I could think of is having an "focus" event and then do what I want to do whenever it's fired. I hope that sounds clear (otherwise forgive me. I'm not very English speaking :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if(iframe.addEventListener)
   iframe.addEventListener('load', func, true);
else if(iframe.attachEvent)
   iframe.attachEvent('onload',func);
```

Comment: Thank you Sudhir. I did try using attachEvent but I forgot to change the event parameter "focus" to "onfocus". Works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support [addEventListener](http://rubayathasan.com/tutorial/ie8-addeventlistener-alternative-example/).